# svg icon doesn't change color on hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

I'm trying to change the color of an icon on hover. my icon consists of a circle around the image. Here is my svg-code

```
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="#212121" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M20 17.3965C18.5664 17.3965 17.3965 18.5664 17.3965 20C17.3965 21.4336 18.5664 22.6035 20 22.6035C21.4336 22.6035 22.6035 21.4336 22.6035 20C22.6035 18.5664 21.4336 17.3965 20 17.3965ZM27.8086 20C27.8086 18.9218 27.8183 17.8535 27.7578 16.7773C27.6972 15.5273 27.4121 14.4179 26.498 13.5039C25.582 12.5879 24.4746 12.3047 23.2246 12.2441C22.1465 12.1836 21.0781 12.1933 20.0019 12.1933C18.9238 12.1933 17.8554 12.1836 16.7793 12.2441C15.5293 12.3047 14.4199 12.5898 13.5058 13.5039C12.5898 14.4199 12.3066 15.5273 12.2461 16.7773C12.1855 17.8554 12.1953 18.9238 12.1953 20C12.1953 21.0761 12.1855 22.1465 12.2461 23.2226C12.3066 24.4726 12.5918 25.582 13.5058 26.4961C14.4218 27.4121 15.5293 27.6953 16.7793 27.7558C17.8574 27.8164 18.9258 27.8066 20.0019 27.8066C21.08 27.8066 22.1484 27.8164 23.2246 27.7558C24.4746 27.6953 25.584 27.4101 26.498 26.4961C27.414 25.58 27.6972 24.4726 27.7578 23.2226C27.8203 22.1465 27.8086 21.0781 27.8086 20ZM20 24.0058C17.7832 24.0058 15.9941 22.2168 15.9941 20C15.9941 17.7832 17.7832 15.9941 20 15.9941C22.2168 15.9941 24.0058 17.7832 24.0058 20C24.0058 22.2168 22.2168 24.0058 20 24.0058ZM24.1699 16.7656C23.6523 16.7656 23.2343 16.3476 23.2343 15.83C23.2343 15.3125 23.6523 14.8945 24.1699 14.8945C24.6875 14.8945 25.1054 15.3125 25.1054 15.83C25.1056 15.953 25.0815 16.0747 25.0345 16.1882C24.9876 16.3018 24.9187 16.405 24.8318 16.4919C24.7449 16.5788 24.6417 16.6477 24.5281 16.6947C24.4145 16.7417 24.2928 16.7657 24.1699 16.7656Z" fill="#212121"/>
<circle cx="20" cy="20" r="19.25" stroke="#212121" stroke-width="1.5"/>
</svg>
```

How to change the icon color to #7210FF on hover? [this is what I got now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZeAr.png)

```
const socials = [
  {
    icon: (
      <IcFB
        className='hover:fill-primary-500'
        width={40}
        height={40}
      />
    ),
    title: 'Facebook',
    url: '#',
  },
  {
    icon: (
      <IcInstagram
        className='hover:fill-primary-500'
        width={40}
        height={40}
      />
    ),
    title: 'Instagram',
    url: '#',
  },
]

const Socials: FC = observer(() => {
  return (
    <div className='flex space-x-4'>
      {socials.map((s) => (
        <LinkWrapper key={s.url} href={s.url} title={s.title} target='_blank'>
          {s.icon}
        </LinkWrapper>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: Are you using basic html, react or some other framework? Or can you provide any other piece of code where this svg is used. If I have used svg's basic styling with css has been enough t change the color on hover

Comment: We need a bit more information for that. Like the relevant CSS, some HTML and how the svg is embedded in your page. Basically a little example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: There should be a few https://css-tricks.com articles on this